# cx_Oracle on Docker : DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, docker, cx-oracle

I'm trying to build a Docker image with cx_Oracle.

Here is the Dockerfile I'm using :

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

ARG release=18
ARG update=3

RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && \
     yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient && \
     yum -y install oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basic && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum

COPY ./fetch_session_iptv.py /opt/
COPY ./conf/fetch_session_iptv.conf /opt/conf/
#COPY ./conf/certs/* /opt/conf/certs/
COPY ./logs /opt/logs

RUN yum install -y \
    #https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm \
    https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm \
    https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm

COPY ./python_requirements/elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
COPY ./python_requirements/certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
COPY ./python_requirements/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl .

RUN pip3 install --user \
    certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl


#CMD ["/bin/bash"]

CMD [ "python3", "/opt/fetch_session_iptv.py" ]
```

This is directly from Oracle documentation : [ODPI-C Installation](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux)

The image seems to build correctly :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.214GB
Step 1/13 : FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
 ---> 7442ca158991
Step 2/13 : ARG release=18
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a9601d8b5721
Step 3/13 : ARG update=3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c82b94480af
Step 4/13 : RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 &&      yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient &&      yum -y install oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basic &&      rm -rf /var/cache/yum
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aadfe1be7fe3
Step 5/13 : COPY ./fetch_session_iptv.py /opt/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b3346172a4d4
Step 6/13 : COPY ./conf/fetch_session_iptv.conf /opt/conf/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a0b0def735fc
Step 7/13 : COPY ./logs /opt/logs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 32e1a82972f7
Step 8/13 : RUN yum install -y  https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm     https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm
 ---> Running in 50a6545982aa
Loaded plugins: ovl
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-5QFxy8/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm: python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-5QFxy8/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-5QFxy8/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm: python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-5QFxy8/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64 0:7.0-1.0.2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 3.6 for package: python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
---> Package python36-pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.0.1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python3.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python3-pip for package: python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python3-setuptools for package: python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64
---> Package python3-libs.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.1()(64bit) for package: python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtirpc.x86_64 0:0.2.4-0.16.el7 will be installed
---> Package python3-pip.noarch 0:9.0.3-7.el7_8 will be installed
---> Package python3-setuptools.noarch 0:39.2.0-10.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package            Arch   Version           Repository                    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 python36-cx_Oracle x86_64 7.0-1.0.2.el7     /python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
                                                                          1.3 M
 python36-pytz      noarch 2016.10-2.0.1.el7 /python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch
                                                                          919 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libtirpc           x86_64 0.2.4-0.16.el7    ol7_latest                    89 k
 python3            x86_64 3.6.8-13.0.1.el7  ol7_latest                    69 k
 python3-libs       x86_64 3.6.8-13.0.1.el7  ol7_latest                   7.0 M
 python3-pip        noarch 9.0.3-7.el7_8     ol7_latest                   1.8 M
 python3-setuptools noarch 39.2.0-10.el7     ol7_latest                   628 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  2 Packages (+5 Dependent packages)

Total size: 12 M
Total download size: 9.5 M
Installed size: 50 M
Downloading packages:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                              1.5 MB/s | 9.5 MB  00:06     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : libtirpc-0.2.4-0.16.el7.x86_64                               1/7 
  Installing : python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                         2/7 
  Installing : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch                      3/7 
  Installing : python3-pip-9.0.3-7.el7_8.noarch                             4/7 
  Installing : python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                              5/7 
  Installing : python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64                      6/7 
  Installing : python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch                       7/7 
  Verifying  : python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                              1/7 
  Verifying  : libtirpc-0.2.4-0.16.el7.x86_64                               2/7 
  Verifying  : python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64                      3/7 
  Verifying  : python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                         4/7 
  Verifying  : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch                      5/7 
  Verifying  : python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch                       6/7 
  Verifying  : python3-pip-9.0.3-7.el7_8.noarch                             7/7 

Installed:
  python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64 0:7.0-1.0.2.el7                                     
  python36-pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.0.1.el7                                      

Dependency Installed:
  libtirpc.x86_64 0:0.2.4-0.16.el7           python3.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7  
  python3-libs.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7     python3-pip.noarch 0:9.0.3-7.el7_8 
  python3-setuptools.noarch 0:39.2.0-10.el7 

Complete!
Removing intermediate container 50a6545982aa
 ---> 3345ba39b755
Step 9/13 : COPY ./python_requirements/elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
 ---> dcc4f0c5a5c5
Step 10/13 : COPY ./python_requirements/certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
 ---> e47c23f75225
Step 11/13 : COPY ./python_requirements/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
 ---> f850ea09150d
Step 12/13 : RUN pip3 install --user    certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl     elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 ---> Running in d01bf60be689
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Processing /certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi, urllib3, elasticsearch
Successfully installed certifi-2020.4.5.2 elasticsearch-7.8.0 urllib3-1.25.9
Removing intermediate container d01bf60be689
 ---> 4d38468f3a00
Step 13/13 : CMD [ "python3", "/opt/fetch_session_iptv.py" ]
 ---> Running in c2fdb466cd69
Removing intermediate container c2fdb466cd69
 ---> a614ef5071ac
Successfully built a614ef5071ac
Successfully tagged kansas-fetch:1.5-SNAPSHOT
```

But when I try to run it I get the following error message, even though Oracle Client is supposed to be installed :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
python_metro_kansas_sql |   File "/opt/fetch_session_iptv.py", line 27, in <module>
python_metro_kansas_sql |     with cx_Oracle.connect("test","test", "test") as connection:
python_metro_kansas_sql | cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
```

Any idea how to fix this?

I tried with different versions for Oracle Client and cx_Oracle, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RPMs prior to 19c, you need to update the system library search path when you install Instant Client RPMs.  The recommended way is to use `ldconfig` as shown in [Oracle's sample 18c Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/18/Dockerfile#L25-L26):

```
RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 \
     yum -y install oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basic oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-devel oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-sqlplus && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
     echo /usr/lib/oracle/${release}.${update}/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}.conf && \
     ldconfig
```

However you should use 19c instead which automatically does this during the RPM package install, see the [sample Instant Client 19c Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19/Dockerfile).  The 19c version will let your apps connect to the same DB versions that the 18c Instant Client will, so there is no point using the older version.

(Note with Instant Client 19c ZIP file you still need to manually set the system library search path).

Comment: There are some Python Dockerfiles from the Oracle Linux group on https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers